# Challenge Representing mongo db domain model on a diagram

Tags: mongodb, uml, relationship, nosql

I am doing a thesis showing the use of technology to allow public health agencies to be warned about potential epidemic outbreak.

I will be using mongodb since data fed into the system is expected to `grow significantly`. I'm writing my synopsis/documentation and am supposed to do a `domain model`. I'm wondering how to represent subdocument.

I'm still a newbie in `NoSQL`, key/value pair database so i am not focusing too much on having the right domain but rather how to represent it. I have a document which is a list of symptoms.`DrugSymptomMapper` and `PathologySymptomMapper` share that list of symptoms by keeping their ids.There is Post which is essentially GPS details and patient details(no name ,contact etc) with either list of Drugs if it's `pharmacy sales` or `Diagnostics` if it's a patient in a clinics/hospital. `DrugsDetails` and `DignosticsDetails` are really `subdocument` of Post.

Kindly check the picture and advise on how these subdocument and relation between documents can be represented. I am using www.draw.io thanks

[image]

Comment: Isn't a sub document really like another class (possibly private/internal to another class)? It's just a named property of a certain type? Relationships can be established like a foreign key in a DB design.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, it isn't really clear for me. I also haven't seen much resources around the representation of the model, what is quite surprise regarding the mongodb documentations and tutorials.

Comment: What isn't really clear for you? A MongoDB document structure is very similar to a class structure. Classes = document, properties = fields with types. A "namespace" could represent a document collection if you wanted.